# Bootstrap not working with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I installed bootstrap but it is not working properly with my rails application.
My application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .

 */
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'  
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
```

Application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Here is how the navigation bar is coming:-
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjKyW.png

Comment: open web developer console and see what is failing in loading

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery..dont know that to Make of it

Comment: try adding these two lines in beginning on application.js 
`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs`

Comment: couldn't find file 'jquery' with type 'application/javascript'

Comment: is `gem 'jquery-rails'` present in your `Gemfile`. If not then add it, `bundle install`, restart rails and check back

Comment: Okay,now there is no error in the console but the nav bar is still the same

Comment: are you using bootstrap-4 or 3? For 4, you will need to follow https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem

Comment: I followed that only.The problem is that in my application.html.erb file  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> It is searching for application.css not .scss hw do I go bout this

Comment: `mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`. If you already have `application.scss`, then `rm app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`